# "Debug ip eigrp" command, output interpretation?

Tags: cisco, eigrp

"Debug ip eigrp" command, output interpretation?

as you see in this output, it's a line from "Show ip eigrp" command, output

IP-EIGRP(Default-IP-Routing-Table:90): Int 172.30.7.0/24 M 2297856 - 1657856 640000 SM 128256 - 256 128000

what is SM (I think it's source metric or AD, not sure!)? what is M (it must be FD, but not sure again!)?what are those numbers in front of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an EIGRP received route advertisement and can be broken down as follows:

`IP-EIGRP(90): Int 172.30.7.0/24 M 2297856 - 1657856 640000 SM 128256 - 256 128000`

Route type and advertised IP Prefix:

- `Int (Internal) 172.30.7.0/24`

The Metric (`M`) is the FD:

- `M 2297856(FD) - 1657856(bandwidth) + 640000(delay)`

The Source Metric (`SM`) is the AD:

- `SM 128256(AD) - 256(bandwidth) + 128000(delay)`